# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'log_softmax'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

while trying to finetune inception_V3 for my own dataset by changing the last fc layer like

```
last_layer =nn.Linear(n_inputs, len(classes))
inception_v3.fc = last_layer
```

after that when I train it got this error on this position

```
    # on training loop
    output = inception_v3(data)
    # calculate the batch loss
    loss = criterion(output, target)
```

Error is

```
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'log_softmax'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a well known problem.

Try one the following solutions:

1. disable aux_logits when the model is created here by also passing `aux_logits=False` to the inception_v3 function.
2. edit your train function to accept and unpack the returned tuple to be something like: `output, aux = model(input_var)`

Check the following [link](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/302#issuecomment-341163548) for more info.

Comment: solved by doing 

       inception_v3 = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
       inception_v3.aux_logits=False

Answer (score 4):

This problem seams to me like instead you define `F`:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
```

You in accident have set `F` to some tuple

```
F=(1,2)
```

And then when you call `F.log_softmax` you get exactly this error.

[image]